# Meet "INTERNAL ERROR: Please contact your support." when configure SAML web SSO on WebSphere Application server

Tags: websphere, saml, pingfederate

I am working on configuring Web SSO using SAML2 on WebSphere Application Server with PingFederate as IDP.

What I have done is,

1. Download and install WebSphere Application Server and the version is 9.0.0.5
2. Installed a Sample Web Application for test.
3. Configure WebSphere Trust Association Interceptor for SAML based on this document, https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was/9.0.5?topic=users-saml-web-single-sign.
4. Verify Connection by using an IDP-initiated SSO and got an "INTERNAL ERROR: Please contact your support." issue.

I can see that a SAML response is sent from IDP to WebSphere and the server sends a successful response but I cannot figure out why users cannot be redirected to the Target URL. I have set the debug level to fine and cannot find any error. Additionally, the error URL also does not work.

After I add an "&TARGET=TARGETURL" behind the SSO link it can redirect the user to the "TARGETURL" after the SAML SSO however the relay state should be handled by SP rather than IDP.

I wonder did I make some mistakes or miss some configurations that caused this issue.

Also, I uploaded part of trace log which should be the part that it receive SAML response from the IDP.

```
[21-9-21 15:38:53:460 EDT] 000000d9 EJSWebCollabo >  preInvoke Entry
[21-9-21 15:38:53:460 EDT] 000000d9 EJSWebCollabo <  preInvoke Exit
                                 <null>
[21-9-21 15:38:53:460 EDT] 000000d9 EJSWebCollabo >  preInvoke Entry
                                 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletRequest@99083b5f
                                 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse@f46dafbe
                                 samlsps
                                 default_host
                                 IBMWebSphereSamlACSListenerServlet
                                 true
[21-9-21 15:38:53:461 EDT] 000000d9 EJSWebCollabo 3   Http Header names and values:
Host=[localhost:9443]
Connection=[keep-alive]
Content-Length=[3361]
Cache-Control=[max-age=0]
sec-ch-ua=["Google Chrome";v="93", " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="93"]
sec-ch-ua-mobile=[?0]
sec-ch-ua-platform=["Windows"]
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests=[1]
Origin=[https://localhost:9031]
Content-Type=[application/x-www-form-urlencoded]
User-Agent=[Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82 Safari/537.36]
Accept=[text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9]
Sec-Fetch-Site=[same-site]
Sec-Fetch-Mode=[navigate]
Sec-Fetch-Dest=[document]
Referer=[https://localhost:9031/]
Accept-Encoding=[gzip, deflate, br]
Accept-Language=[en-US,en;q=0.9,zh-TW;q=0.8,zh;q=0.7,zh-CN;q=0.6]
Cookie=[PF=slGINjz4m5kSL7gpbfdUlA]

[21-9-21 15:38:53:461 EDT] 000000d9 EJSWebCollabo 3    Request Context Path=/samlsps, Servlet Path=, Path Info=/acs
[21-9-21 15:38:53:461 EDT] 000000d9 WebSecurityCo >  <init> Entry
                                 <null>
                                 <null>
                                 <null>
[21-9-21 15:38:53:461 EDT] 000000d9 WebSecurityCo <  <init> Exit
                                 com.ibm.ws.security.web.WebSecurityContext@936c75b7
[21-9-21 15:38:53:461 EDT] 000000d9 WebCollaborat >  SetUnauthenticatedSubjectIfNeeded Entry
[21-9-21 15:38:53:461 EDT] 000000d9 WebCollaborat 3   Invoked and received Subject are null, setting it anonymous/unauthenticated.
[21-9-21 15:38:53:461 EDT] 000000d9 WebCollaborat <  SetUnauthenticatedSubjectIfNeeded:true Exit
[21-9-21 15:38:53:461 EDT] 000000d9 WebCollaborat 3   com.ibm.ws.security.web.WebCollaborator.WebComponentMetaData attribute is set.
[21-9-21 15:38:53:461 EDT] 000000d9 EJSWebCollabo 3   WebComponentMetaData
                                 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.metadata.WebComponentMetaDataImpl@476b7334[WebSphereSamlSP#WebSphereSamlSPWeb.war#IBMWebSphereSamlACSListenerServlet]
[21-9-21 15:38:53:461 EDT] 000000d9 EJSWebCollabo 3   preInvoke pushing app name WebSphereSamlSP
[21-9-21 15:38:53:461 EDT] 000000d9 WebSecurityCo 3   Setting pushed security to "true" for: com.ibm.ws.security.web.WebSecurityContext@936c75b7
[21-9-21 15:38:53:461 EDT] 000000d9 EJSWebCollabo 3   preInvoke
                                 app_name=WebSphereSamlSP isAdminApp=false isAppSecurityOn=false
[21-9-21 15:38:53:461 EDT] 000000d9 EJSWebCollabo 3   preInvoke
                                 Skip authorization for non-system apps when app security is disabled.
[21-9-21 15:38:53:461 EDT] 000000d9 IBMWebSphereS >  handleRedirect Entry
[21-9-21 15:38:53:464 EDT] 000000d9 IBMWebSphereS 3   samlres[not null]
[21-9-21 15:38:53:464 EDT] 000000d9 IBMWebSphereS 3   target[null]
[21-9-21 15:38:53:464 EDT] 000000d9 IBMWebSphereS 3   RelayState[null]
[21-9-21 15:38:53:464 EDT] 000000d9 IBMWebSphereS >  getTarget(relayStateUri[null],decodeURL[true] Entry
[21-9-21 15:38:53:464 EDT] 000000d9 IBMWebSphereS 3   The RelayState is not a URL. target URL.
[21-9-21 15:38:53:467 EDT] 000000d9 IBMWebSphereS <  handleRedirect Exit
[21-9-21 15:38:53:467 EDT] 000000d9 EJSWebCollabo >  postInvoke Entry
                                 com.ibm.ws.security.web.WebSecurityContext@936c75b7
[21-9-21 15:38:53:467 EDT] 000000d9 EJSWebCollabo 3   Resetting invoked: null and received: nullsubjects
[21-9-21 15:38:53:468 EDT] 000000d9 WebSecurityCo 3   Getting pushed security value "true" for: com.ibm.ws.security.web.WebSecurityContext@936c75b7
[21-9-21 15:38:53:468 EDT] 000000d9 EJSWebCollabo 3   postInvoke popped resource WebSphereSamlSP of type Application
[21-9-21 15:38:53:468 EDT] 000000d9 EJSWebCollabo <  postInvoke Exit
[21-9-21 15:38:53:468 EDT] 000000d9 EJSWebCollabo >  postInvoke Entry
                                 <null>
[21-9-21 15:38:53:468 EDT] 000000d9 EJSWebCollabo <  postInvoke Exit
```

After I enabled the app security, I will be redirected to the login.errorUrl. In the log I can see that WebSphere received SAML response but somehow it cannot handle it. I think I have uploaded signer certificate on the WebSphere and set "trustAnysigner" to "true". Here is some part of the log:

```
[21-9-22 15:05:07:971 EDT] 000000c0 ACSTrustAssoc 3   Sending redirect
[21-9-22 15:05:07:972 EDT] 000000c0 ACSTrustAssoc <  createTAIErrorResult Exit
[21-9-22 15:05:07:972 EDT] 000000c0 ACSTrustAssoc 3   SAMLResponse could not be verified. Auto Re-login. 
[21-9-22 15:05:07:972 EDT] 000000c0 ACSTrustAssoc <  invokeTAIbeforeSSO:null Exit
[21-9-22 15:05:07:972 EDT] 000000c0 ACSTrustAssoc <  negotiateValidateandEstablishTrust returns [not null] Exit
[21-9-22 15:05:07:972 EDT] 000000c0 TAIWrapper    <  negotiateAndValidateEstablishedTrust(): status code = 403 Exit
[21-9-22 15:05:07:972 EDT] 000000c0 WebAuthentica <  Exiting with TAI_CHALLENGE Exit
[21-9-22 15:05:07:972 EDT] 000000c0 WebAuthentica 3   result status is 5
[21-9-22 15:05:07:972 EDT] 000000c0 WebAuthentica <  authenticate Exit
                                 AuthenticationResult.TAI_CHALLENGE
[21-9-22 15:05:07:972 EDT] 000000c0 WebCollaborat 3   isAuthenticate is false
[21-9-22 15:05:07:972 EDT] 000000c0 WebRequestImp >  getAppVHost Entry
[21-9-22 15:05:07:972 EDT] 000000c0 WebRequestImp <  getAppVHost Exit
                                 appVHost=default_host
                                 isVHostAndContextRootSet=true
[21-9-22 15:05:07:972 EDT] 000000c0 WebCollaborat >  validSecAttrs Entry
                                 default_host:samlsps
                                 /acs
                                 POST
                                 false
                                 WebSphereSamlSP
                                 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletRequest@5ae9cdc7
                                 default_host
                                 false
[21-9-22 15:05:07:972 EDT] 000000c0 WebAppCache   >  getWebAccessContext Entry
                                 WebSphereSamlSP
                                 default_host:samlsps
                                 false
[21-9-22 15:05:07:972 EDT] 000000c0 WebAppCache   3   Okay, I found the entry for [WebSphereSamlSP:default_host:samlsps]
[21-9-22 15:05:07:972 EDT] 000000c0 WebAppCache   <  getWebAccessContext Exit
[21-9-22 15:05:07:973 EDT] 000000c0 WebAccessCont >  WebAccessContext with ServletMap Entry
[21-9-22 15:05:07:973 EDT] 000000c0 WebAccessCont <  WebAccessContext with ServletMap Exit
[21-9-22 15:05:07:973 EDT] 000000c0 WebConstraint >  getConstraints:  Entry
                                 /acs
                                 POST
[21-9-22 15:05:07:973 EDT] 000000c0 WebConstraint 3   webConstraintsTable.length = 1
[21-9-22 15:05:07:973 EDT] 000000c0 WebResourceCo >  isStandardHTTPMethod Entry
                                 POST
[21-9-22 15:05:07:973 EDT] 000000c0 WebResourceCo <  isStandardHTTPMethod Exit
                                 true
[21-9-22 15:05:07:973 EDT] 000000c0 WebConstraint 3   Looking at webResourceCollectionConstraints with URL patterns: 
[21-9-22 15:05:07:973 EDT] 000000c0 WebConstraint 3           url: /*
[21-9-22 15:05:07:973 EDT] 000000c0 WebResourceCo >  matches Entry
                                 /acs
                                 POST
                                 true
[21-9-22 15:05:07:973 EDT] 000000c0 WebResourceCo 3    .... check if in http methods list
[21-9-22 15:05:07:973 EDT] 000000c0 WebResourceCo 3   memberOfList, methodName: POST methodList[0]: GET
[21-9-22 15:05:07:973 EDT] 000000c0 WebResourceCo 3   memberOfList, methodName: POST methodList[1]: PUT
[21-9-22 15:05:07:973 EDT] 000000c0 WebResourceCo 3   memberOfList, methodName: POST methodList[2]: HEAD
[21-9-22 15:05:07:973 EDT] 000000c0 WebResourceCo 3   memberOfList, methodName: POST methodList[3]: TRACE
[21-9-22 15:05:07:973 EDT] 000000c0 WebResourceCo 3   memberOfList, methodName: POST methodList[4]: POST
[21-9-22 15:05:07:973 EDT] 000000c0 WebResourceCo 3   methodName is in methodList, returning true
[21-9-22 15:05:07:973 EDT] 000000c0 WebResourceCo >  isStandardHTTPMethod Entry
                                 POST
[21-9-22 15:05:07:973 EDT] 000000c0 WebResourceCo <  isStandardHTTPMethod Exit
                                 true
[21-9-22 15:05:07:973 EDT] 000000c0 WebResourceCo 3    .... check if in http omission methods list
[21-9-22 15:05:07:973 EDT] 000000c0 WebResourceCo 3   methodName is not in methodList, returning false
[21-9-22 15:05:07:973 EDT] 000000c0 WebResourceCo 3   -- Checking methods -- 
 validateAllMethods: false existMethodsList :true memberOfMethodList :true isStandardHTTPMethod :true allowCustomHTTPMethods :true
 existOmissionMethodsList :false memberOfOmissionMethodList :false
[21-9-22 15:05:07:973 EDT] 000000c0 WebResourceCo 3    .... check if in http methods list
[21-9-22 15:05:07:973 EDT] 000000c0 WebResourceCo 3   memberOfList, methodName: POST methodList[0]: GET
[21-9-22 15:05:07:973 EDT] 000000c0 WebResourceCo 3   memberOfList, methodName: POST methodList[1]: PUT
[21-9-22 15:05:07:973 EDT] 000000c0 WebResourceCo 3   memberOfList, methodName: POST methodList[2]: HEAD
[21-9-22 15:05:07:973 EDT] 000000c0 WebResourceCo 3   memberOfList, methodName: POST methodList[3]: TRACE
[21-9-22 15:05:07:973 EDT] 000000c0 WebResourceCo 3   memberOfList, methodName: POST methodList[4]: POST
[21-9-22 15:05:07:973 EDT] 000000c0 WebResourceCo 3   methodName is in methodList, returning true
[21-9-22 15:05:07:973 EDT] 000000c0 WebResourceCo 3   Checking URL: /*
[21-9-22 15:05:07:973 EDT] 000000c0 WebResourceCo <  matches (PathName) : /* Exit
[21-9-22 15:05:07:973 EDT] 000000c0 WebConstraint <  getConstraints not null Exit
[21-9-22 15:05:07:973 EDT] 000000c0 WebCollaborat >  unprotectedSpecialURI Entry
                                 webAppName[WebSphereSamlSPWeb]
isProtected[true]
realm[Default Realm]
challengeType[BASIC]
authMechanism[LTPA]
SSLEnabled[false]
SSOEnabled[true]
secureSSO[false]
defaultToBasic[false]
LTPACookieName[LtpaToken]
loginCookieName[null]
CookieSuffix[null]
                                 /acs
                                 POST
                                 REQUEST
[21-9-22 15:05:07:973 EDT] 000000c0 WebCollaborat <  unprotectedSpecialURI Exit
                                 <null>
[21-9-22 15:05:07:973 EDT] 000000c0 WebCollaborat <  validSecAttrs Exit
                                 <null>
[21-9-22 15:05:07:973 EDT] 000000c0 WebCollaborat 3    List of required roles for uri /acs is: 
[21-9-22 15:05:07:973 EDT] 000000c0 WebCollaborat 3    required role: WebSphereSamlAcsRole
[21-9-22 15:05:07:973 EDT] 000000c0 WebRequestImp >  getAppContextRoot Entry
[21-9-22 15:05:07:973 EDT] 000000c0 WebRequestImp <  getAppContextRoot Exit
                                 appContextRoot=samlsps
                                 isVHostAndContextRootSet=true
[21-9-22 15:05:07:973 EDT] 000000c0 WebRequestImp >  getAppVHost Entry
[21-9-22 15:05:07:973 EDT] 000000c0 WebRequestImp <  getAppVHost Exit
                                 appVHost=default_host
                                 isVHostAndContextRootSet=true
[21-9-22 15:05:07:973 EDT] 000000c0 WebCollaborat >  isURIBoundByConstraint Entry
                                 WebSphereSamlSP
                                 samlsps
                                 default_host
                                 /acs
[21-9-22 15:05:07:973 EDT] 000000c0 WebAppCache   >  getWebAccessContext Entry
                                 WebSphereSamlSP
                                 default_host:samlsps
                                 false
[21-9-22 15:05:07:973 EDT] 000000c0 WebAppCache   3   Okay, I found the entry for [WebSphereSamlSP:default_host:samlsps]
[21-9-22 15:05:07:973 EDT] 000000c0 WebAppCache   <  getWebAccessContext Exit
[21-9-22 15:05:07:973 EDT] 000000c0 WebAccessCont >  WebAccessContext with ServletMap Entry
[21-9-22 15:05:07:973 EDT] 000000c0 WebAccessCont <  WebAccessContext with ServletMap Exit
[21-9-22 15:05:07:973 EDT] 000000c0 WebConstraint >  existsExactMatchURI Entry
                                 /acs
[21-9-22 15:05:07:973 EDT] 000000c0 WebConstraint 3   webConstraintsTable.length = 1
[21-9-22 15:05:07:973 EDT] 000000c0 WebConstraint <  existsExactMatchURI : no match, returning false Exit
[21-9-22 15:05:07:973 EDT] 000000c0 WebCollaborat <  isURIBoundByConstraint Exit
                                 false
[21-9-22 15:05:07:973 EDT] 000000c0 WebCollaborat 3   isURIBound for uri: /acs: false
[21-9-22 15:05:07:973 EDT] 000000c0 WebCollaborat 3   securityConstraints for uri /acs are: com.ibm.ws.security.web.WebResourceCollectionConstraints@393f3b2b
[21-9-22 15:05:07:973 EDT] 000000c0 WebCollaborat 3   URI -  /acs.POST is protected
[21-9-22 15:05:07:973 EDT] 000000c0 WebCollaborat 3   Saving previous subject null
[21-9-22 15:05:07:973 EDT] 000000c0 WebCollaborat >  checkAuthStatus Entry
                                 AuthenticationResult.TAI_CHALLENGE
                                 webAppName[WebSphereSamlSPWeb]
isProtected[true]
realm[Default Realm]
challengeType[BASIC]
authMechanism[LTPA]
SSLEnabled[false]
SSOEnabled[true]
secureSSO[false]
defaultToBasic[false]
LTPACookieName[LtpaToken]
loginCookieName[null]
CookieSuffix[null]
[21-9-22 15:05:07:974 EDT] 000000c0 TAIChallengeR >  TAIChallengeReply(403) Entry
[21-9-22 15:05:07:974 EDT] 000000c0 TAIChallengeR <  TAIChallengeReply() Exit
[21-9-22 15:05:07:974 EDT] 000000c0 WebCollaborat 3   TAI authentication challenge - sending 403
[21-9-22 15:05:07:974 EDT] 000000c0 WebCollaborat <  checkAuthStatus 3 Exit
                                 com.ibm.ws.security.web.TAIChallengeReply@54049520
[21-9-22 15:05:07:974 EDT] 000000c0 WebCollaborat <  authorize Exit
                                 com.ibm.ws.security.web.TAIChallengeReply@54049520
[21-9-22 15:05:07:974 EDT] 000000c0 EJSWebCollabo >  handleException Entry
                                 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletRequest@5ae9cdc7
                                 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse@25d3a5e1
                                 com.ibm.ws.security.web.WebSecurityException
    at com.ibm.ws.security.web.EJSWebCollaborator.preInvoke(EJSWebCollaborator.java:451)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.collaborator.WebAppSecurityCollaboratorImpl.preInvoke(WebAppSecurityCollaboratorImpl.java:230)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.collaborator.CollaboratorHelper.preInvokeCollaborators(CollaboratorHelper.java:436)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1101)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4219)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.handleRequest(WebAppImpl.java:2210)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1030)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:382)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:465)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:532)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:318)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:289)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.determineNextChannel(SSLConnectionLink.java:1187)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.readyInboundPostHandshake(SSLConnectionLink.java:768)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink$MyHandshakeCompletedCallback.complete(SSLConnectionLink.java:464)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLUtils.handleHandshake(SSLUtils.java:1137)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLHandshakeIOCallback.complete(SSLHandshakeIOCallback.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1909)

[21-9-22 15:05:07:976 EDT] 000000c0 EJSWebCollabo 3   Response is already committed
[21-9-22 15:05:07:976 EDT] 000000c0 EJSWebCollabo 3   com.ibm.websphere.security.allow.committed.response is false
[21-9-22 15:05:07:976 EDT] 000000c0 WebSecurityCo 3   Getting pushed security value "true" for: com.ibm.ws.security.web.WebSecurityContext@9d8e0360
[21-9-22 15:05:07:976 EDT] 000000c0 EJSWebCollabo 3   handleException popped resource WebSphereSamlSP of type Application
[21-9-22 15:05:07:976 EDT] 000000c0 WebSecurityCo 3   Getting pushed admin value "false" for: com.ibm.ws.security.web.WebSecurityContext@9d8e0360
[21-9-22 15:05:07:976 EDT] 000000c0 EJSWebCollabo <  handleException Exit
[21-9-22 15:05:07:976 EDT] 000000c0 EJSWebCollabo >  postInvoke Entry
                                 com.ibm.ws.security.web.WebSecurityContext@9d8e0360
[21-9-22 15:05:07:976 EDT] 000000c0 EJSWebCollabo 3   Resetting invoked: null and received: nullsubjects
[21-9-22 15:05:07:976 EDT] 000000c0 WebSecurityCo 3   Getting pushed security value "true" for: com.ibm.ws.security.web.WebSecurityContext@9d8e0360
[21-9-22 15:05:07:976 EDT] 000000c0 EJSWebCollabo 3   postInvoke popped null resource
[21-9-22 15:05:07:976 EDT] 000000c0 EJSWebCollabo <  postInvoke Exit
[21-9-22 15:05:07:976 EDT] 000000c0 EJSWebCollabo >  postInvoke Entry
                                 <null>
[21-9-22 15:05:07:976 EDT] 000000c0 EJSWebCollabo <  postInvoke Exit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How is the targetUrl configured on the WAS side? There are three different ways that WAS can determine its targetUrl. In order of precedence:

1. From the WASSamlSpReqUrl cookie generated on step 3 of a "bookmark style" login as described on this page: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was/9.0.5?topic=sign-saml-single-scenarios-features-limitations
2. From the RelayState parameter sent by the IdP
3. From the sso_.sp.targetUrl parameter

The following trace specification will show details about how the targetUrl is being determined:

*=info:com.ibm.ws.security.web.*=all:com.ibm.ws.security.saml.*=all:com.ibm.websphere.wssecurity.*=all:com.ibm.ws.wssecurity.*=all:com.ibm.ws.wssecurity.platform.audit.*=off

If you have a trace with that specification please feel free to upload it here and I'd be happy to take a look as well.

Also just as a side-note, I would recommend updating to the latest WAS fixpack if possible. There have been some logging improvements to the SAML runtime that might be helpful for this type of situation.

Comment: Actually, I am using the third method, by setting up a "sso_1.sp.tragetUrl=TARGETURL". And you mean I should look for this trace specification in my trace log to figure out which targetUrl is being used. Would you like to explain what does this specification mean actually.

Comment: I have uploaded the trace log that should have included the SAML transaction part.  Would you like to take a look for me?

Comment: Based on the snippet you posted, I think the problem is that the TAI is not invoked, because security is not enabled:

[21-9-21 15:38:53:461 EDT] 000000d9 EJSWebCollabo 3   preInvoke
                                 Skip authorization for non-system apps when app security is disabled.

Make sure to enable Application Security in the Global Security panel, then restart the server. Without security enabled, the SAML login is not actually occurring; the page is loading as if it did not have any JEE security-constraints.

Comment: Just a comment from the PingFed side... While doing IdP-init, you can feed a query parameter to the IdP-init URL of `Target` or `TARGETRESOURCE` that is a URLEncoded string. That string will be placed into the `RelayState` attribute of the assertion.

Comment: Thanks for your help and I can see WebSphere received SAML response. However, I will be redirected to the error page when I test this after enabling app security. I have enabled the "trustAnysigner" in TAI properties and uploaded the signing certificate in the WebSphere console. Would you like to help me check the trace log again?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to examine the part of the log that shows the SAML login failing. The new part you pasted seems to be from the initial request where the login.error.page redirect is sent. Later in the log, there should be a line that says "isSamlResponse:true" ... and that thread will eventually get to a point where it prints "sendAuditEvent" indicating whether the SAML login was successful or not. The login error is probably somwhere near the "sendAuditEvent" message. If you are having trouble finding it, please feel free to upload the full log somewhere and I can take a look.